# Mainline linux and fast boot 2019

Tags: boot, kernel

If I install the mainline linux kernel will I get that super fast boot I was reading about?

There is information about installing the mainline generic, but how to install the mainline for the low-latency?  Is it available as well?
Here was the article I read https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Clear-Linux-Kernel-3s-to-300ms

Comment: You'll need to provide a link to what you were reading because my crystal ball isn't telling me.

Comment: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Clear-Linux-Kernel-3s-to-300ms

Comment: The link doesn't say which kernel version the 2 seconds savings will be released in.

Comment: not sure what it means either.. I did install majaro once.. and it was a really fast boot.. maybe it is already in the mainline